# Ideal Class Group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I am trying to understand the ideal class group.
I have seen a few different derivation of this.

Sometimes i read about the ideal class group of a ring of algebraic integers ($\mathcal{O}_K$) and sometimes i read about the ideal class group of an imaginary field $ K =\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$, with $m<0$.
Is there a difference? Because i thought, that a field only has two ideals and hence the definition of ideal class group over a a field does not make much sense to me.

Comment: it's the ideal class group of the ring of integers in the field

Comment: So if they talk about, the ideal class group (or class group) of an algebraic number field K, they always mean the ideal class group of  the ring of integers of that algebraic number field K?

Comment: @headkopf:  yes, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_class_group), for example

Comment: My impression is that the number field itself is the more central object of interest: it determines its own ring of integers; it contains all of the fractional ideals of the ring of integers; it determines its own ideal class group. So it makes sense to speak of the ideal class group of the number field itself.

Comment: It certainly makes sense to speak of the class number of the number field. Still, the definition formally refers to its ring of integers. It would be useful to write down every detail of each definition for, say, $K=\Bbb Q(i)$ and $\mathcal{O}_K=\Bbb Z[i]$.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that a field has only two ideals.  When we speak of the ideal class group of an algebraic number field, we are speaking of the ideal class group of the ring of integers in that field.